# Using custom triplets with vcpkg and CMake in manifest mode

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, vcpkg

I'm trying to configure `vcpkg` to compile dependencies using address sanitizer and thread sanitizer. To do this, I need to pass the compilation flag `-fsanitize=address` or `fsanitize=thread` to all compilation commands. Reading [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/discussions/25068), the best way to do this seems to be to use the "overlay-triplets" feature in `vcpkg`. However, I having some trouble understanding on how exactly this works. Following, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/examples/overlay-triplets-linux-dynamic), I created a `custom-triplets` folder in my project's root directory with two files called `x64-linux-asan` and `x64-linux-tsan`, which look like:

```
set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE x64)
set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE dynamic)
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)

set(VCPKG_CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

set(VCPKG_CXX_FLAGS "${VCPKG_CXX_FLAGS} -fsanitize=address")
```

Now, I don't quite understand how do I configure CMake to use for example the `x64-linux-asan` triplet. I'm using `vcpkg` in [manifest mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/manifests). The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/reference/vcpkg-configuration-json) mention that you can create a `vcpkg-configuration.json` file to use custom triplets, but how does one selected a specific triplet from the custom list of files? I have tried with this:

> cmake -B build -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-linux-asan

but it doesn't work and `vcpkg` complains:

> error: Invalid triplet: x64-linux-asan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use custom triplets you also have to set `VCPKG_OVERLAY_TRIPLETS` variable so vcpkg can find them. Just set it to the directory that contains your custom triplet.

I would recommend setting those variables using cmake presets, so that they are automatically filled:

```
{
  "name": "vcpkg",
  "hidden": true,
  "cacheVariables": {
    "VCPKG_OVERLAY_TRIPLETS": "${sourceDir}/triplets",
    "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "$env{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
  }
},
{
  "name": "linux-asan",
  "hidden": true,
  "cacheVariables": {
    "VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET": "x64-linux-asan"
  }
},
```

With this you can create a cmake presets that inherit from those two, and automatically set all of those CMake variables without baking them into your scripts.